# NSDate convert to 24Hours format

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want my Time to convert it to 24hrs format.

Input: 2014-07-23 07:44:47 +0000

Output: 19:44:47 <<< *I want this format 24hrs*

```
// MY Code
NSLog(@"before %@",selectedDate);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSLog(@"after %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:selectedDate]);
```

this is what I got instead:
[image]

EDIT:

Also tried: `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];`

Result is:[image]

Comment: `@"hh:mm a"` should be replaced with `@"HH:mm:ss"`, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine always understand the concept

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

hh- 12 hour format

HH - 24 hour format 


  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
```

remind that always, K

Comment: @Bordz - in my suggestion in stack overflow already given the much more answers related the date format in iOS, refers more in google before u post the question

Comment: thanks, I've already tried @"HH:mm a" but it gives me different value, for example BEFORE:2014-07-23 08:02:27 +0000 AFTER:16:02 PM. It should be 20:02 right?